# Allow multiple value in shortcode for custom meta field value in wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-fields

I have a shortcode which is working fine if iI put the single value for "rank" in shortcode.

[coaches_list category="dummy" number="3" rank="2"]

But I want to pass multiple values in "rank" as [coaches_list category="dummy" number="3" rank="2", "6"].

'rank' is a numeric type custom field associated with post.

I have searched alot on internet from last 2 days but found no result. Please let me know where I am having mistake.

Here is the piece of shortcode I bulit:

```
$args = array(
        'number' => '-1',
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'category' => '',
        'meta_key'    => '', 
        'rank'  => '', 

    ), $atts )
);

 global $post;


  $html = "";
  $my_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => $number, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'category' =>$category, 'meta_key' => 'rank', 'meta_value' =>  $rank ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for `[coaches_list category="dummy" number="3" rank="2,6"]`

And then you could make an array `$ranks = explode(',',$rank);`.

```
function my_shortcode($atts){
  extract(shortcode_atts( $args = array( 
    'number' => '-1', 
    'orderby' => 'id', 
    'order' => 'desc', 
    'category' => '', 
    'meta_key' => '', 
    'rank' => '', 
  ),$atts)); 

  $ranks = explode(',',$rank); 
  $html = '<ul>';

  $my_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $number, 
    'orderby' => $orderby, 
    'order' => $order, 
    'category' =>$category, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'=>'rank',
        'value'=>$ranks,
        'compare'=>'IN'
    )
  ));

  foreach($my_posts as $rankpost){
    $html .= '<li>'.$rankpost->ID.': '.get_the_title($rankpost->ID).' - Rank: '.get_post_meta($rankpost->ID,'rank',true).'</li>';
  }
  $html .= '</ul>';
  return $html;
}
```

Or maybe you could create a query that gives out all post with rank=2 AND/OR rank=6.

Comment: HI, Thank You but now it display the post associated with the last rank given in array.

Comment: e.g. if i run [coaches_list category="dummy" number="3" rank="2,6"] it display posts associated with "6"

Comment: What are you doing after "$my_query->the_post();" ?

Comment: I tried something else with the `meta_query`. Better now?

Comment: extract( shortcode_atts(
 $args = array(
   'number' => '-1',
   'orderby' => 'id',
   'order' => 'desc',
   'category' => '',
            'meta_key'    => '', 
            'rank'  => '', 

  ), $atts )
 );
  global $post;
      $html = "";
   $ranks = explode(',',$rank);
  
    foreach($ranks as $rank)
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => $number, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'category' =>$category, 'meta_key' => 'rank', 'meta_value' =>  $rank ));
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

Comment: no luck, query not working properly, all posts showing irrespective to rank

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to see the full shortcode function? To test the query I made a function that should give out a list of all posts like: `- 1: Hello World - Rank: 6`

Comment: yes coming all the posts but now what to do in order to display posts with multiple ranks given in shortcode.

Comment: [coaches_list category="dummy" number="3" rank="3,6"] is what i am suing for now but output is:

Comment: 239: post 6 - Rank:
    238: post 3 - Rank:
    236: post 2 - Rank: